# Reading a flag in a boost thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I am kind of a newbie in Boost programming. What I want to do is create a thread from main() which will run continuously until the main() exits. Now, I am doing some operations on that thread and when it is done it will set a boolean flag. The main() will wait for this flag to be set, and when it is 'true' the main() will do its work, reset the flag, and wait for it to be set again. The other thread will run continuously.

Can anyone please provide a simple set of boost thread instructions to achieve this?

I am trying to do this in pseudocode

```
class Call {
public:
    bool flag, do_it;
    keyboard_callback() {
        if('s' pressed) do_it = true;
    }
    f() { // some callback function
        if(do_it == true) flag=true;
    }
    void func() {
        ...register callback f()
        ...register keyboard_callback()
        ...
        while(some condition) { keep running , exit when 'q'}
        ...
    }
};
main()
{
    Call obj;
    boost::thread th (boost::bind(&Call::func, &obj));
    th.detach();
    while(true) {
        while (obj.flag == false);
        ...do something
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// shared variables
boost::mutex mutex;
boost::condition_variable condition;
bool flag = false;

// signal completion
boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mutex);
flag = true;
condition.notify_one();

// waiting in main method
boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mutex);
while (!flag) {
    condition.wait(lock);
}
```